# Highlight sentences in yellow for specific commands such as italic

Tags: highlighting, italic, sentence

**Aim**

To change the background color of a sentence in which italicized words occur that use the `\textit{}` command.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE)**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

This is an example of a sentence that I DO NOT want to highlight. This is an example of a \textit{sentence} that I want to highlight. This is an example of a sentence that I DO NOT want to highlight.

\end{document}
```

**Preferred outcome**

To have the sentence of italicized words highlighted in yellow.

Comment: What you highlight? Sentence which contain some words in italic shape or only highlighted those words?

Comment: All sentences that contain the `\textit` command.

Comment: The simplest way is to put `\hl` at beginning of this sentences :-) ...

Comment: I understand, but I am more looking to renew the command textit.

Comment: Are you willing and able to work with a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: Will sentences only ever be terminated by periods (aka "full stops")? Could sentences also be terminated by question or exclamation marks?

Comment: It is simple to renew command `\textit{...}` that its contents is highlighted, but highlighted whole sentence which contain `\textit{...}` command is another story ... In this case you need to employ AI :-)  based on LuaLaTeX  as stated @Mico in his comments.

Comment: this is impossible in any tex other than luatex. in luatex you could attempt processing the input buffer with patterns matching a sentence, but it would be  a lot more robust to do this in your editor

Comment: @Zarko Ok, thanks for the input. How can you only highlight in yellow words that use the `\textit{}` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\oldtextit\textit                           % <---
\renewcommand{\textit}[1]{\oldtextit{\hl{#1}}}  % <---


\begin{document}

This is an example of a sentence that I DO NOT want to highlight. This is an example of a \textit{sentence} that I want to highlight. This is an example of a sentence that I DO NOT want to highlight.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you asked me in your comment?

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure what exactly the OP is trying to achieve, but I'm still leaning toward the possibility that the objective is to highlight an entire sentence if at least one word in the senence is italicized. That said, I would agree with the view that the comment the OP addressed to you specifically suugests that only individual words rather than entire sentences should be highlighted. Let's see if the OP weighs in and sees fit to clarify the situation.

Comment: @Mico, OP comment surprise me a lot:  I just answer on request in in. However, I completely agree with you. It seems that OP scared when see that possible solution should employ LuaLaTeX :-). Lets wait on his response.